# ld: too many sections (90295)

Tags: windows, haskell, vulkan, haskell-stack

I am trying to build a haskell project from Ludum Dare, but whenever I attempt the build I get an error message saying the object file has too many sections. Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.2\lib\../mingw/bin\ld.exe: .stack-work\dist\a3a5fe88\build\HSsingletons-2.7-J1xRPYS9ah3kGEIOoeLuX.o: too many sections (90295)
singletons           > C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.2\lib\../mingw/bin\ld.exe: final link failed: file too big

--  While building package singletons-2.7 using:
      C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Temp\stack-5ba10ebdb151d9fa\singletons-2.7\.stack-work\dist\a3a5fe88\setup\setup --builddir=.stack-work\dist\a3a5fe88 build --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I am using stack 2.3.3 and Windows 10. The project uses the vulkan library.

I tried adding `-opta-mbig-obj`, but gcc then failed with `error: unrecognized command line option '-mbig-obj'`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may need to try explicitly using the “large object” file format, which I believe you can do by adding `-opta-mbig-obj` or `-Wa,-mbig-obj` to the GHC flags in the project’s build config (`package.yaml` or `.cabal` file) to add `-mbig-obj` to the assembler options. You may also need to add `--oformat pe-bigobj-x86-64` to the linker flags, using (I think) `-optl--oformat -optlpe-bigobj-x86-64` or `-Wl,--oformat,pe-bigobj-x86-64`. Are you using a 32-bit MinGW? I would expect MinGW64 to handle this by default. (And I’m not actually sure whether 32-bit supports these flags, so you may need to upgrade anyway.)

Comment: I dont know what MINGW version I have. Stack automatically installed it.

Comment: I just tried every combination of those flags, and none of them worked. The same error message was show.

Comment: GCC did not recognize the -mbig-obj flag when i tried adding it to vulkan's compilation settings.

Answer (score 1):

Since about a year ago (https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/commit/1ef90f990da90036d481c830d8832e21b8f1571b) GHC already uses the `-mbig-obj` and `--oformat,pe-bigobj-x86-64` when assembling and linking on 64 bit MinGW. Adding these flags manually will not help on recent GHC versions.

I was able to replicate this problem for both the `sdl2` and `vulkan` Haskell packages using Stack, however neither of them exhibit this issue when compiled with Cabal (and `--enable-split-sections`) on Windows; this looks to be a bug in stack.

Comment: I tried building with cabal, and now it is telling me that `vulkan-1` is a missing or bad library. I have already added `--extra-lib-dirs` and `--extra-include-dirs`

Comment: Sorry you're having this trouble, I think it might be best for you to open an issue against the project you're using with precise instructions for reproduction.

Comment: @JoeHermaszewski probably it's worth to file it as a Stack issue? For some that could be a more discoverable and maybe somebody could check out how Stack could cause this kind of a bug.

Comment: Certainly, I mentioned the original package because I'm the author of `vulkan` :)